# Typescript Router navigate()

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, navigation, jhipster

I'm struggling with this error :

> NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/something/create?user=3#new', error:
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'something/create')

I've made this so far :

> some.component.ts

```
constructor( private router: Router ) {}

createNew() {
    const navigateToNewWithUser: NavigationExtras = {
        fragment: 'new',
        queryParams: {'user': this.user.id}
    };

    this.router.navigate(['/something/create'], navigateToNewWithUser);
}
```

> some.component.html

```
<button class="btn add-button float-right jh-create-entity" (click)="createNew()">
```

> some.route.ts

```
{
    path: 'something/create?user=:id#new',
    component: SomeComponent,
    resolve: {
        supervision: UserPageResolver
    },
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
        pageTitle: 'home.create'
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
}
```

All other routes are on the same pattern and work perfectly fine.
I don't get it, since `/something/create?user=3#new` match what I putted in route.ts

I'm working with an Angular 6 projects generated using JHipster.
I tried to change URL, removing `#new`, putting `?user=:id` at the end, and much more, but I end up having the same error all the time.

Any idea ? I've read a bunch of questions about angular routing here, but didn't found an answer to my problem yet.

If you need more code just ask.

Comment: Have you tried `queryParams` from `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: I did, got some unreadable error, looking like Error : [object object], so I went back to what was generated with JHipster.

Comment: First change your router path to `something/create` instead of `path : something/create?user=:id#new`. than use queryParams

Comment: I did, now I've got `path: 'supervision/create/:id'` as suggested in answers below. Please check comments there, there error is still the same.

Comment: Don't use `:id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try something like this,

```
 this.router.navigate(['/something/create'], { queryParams: { user: this.user.id } });
```

change the route to,

```
    { path: 'something/create',  component: SomeComponent }
```

Comment: This worked thanks ! Once `:id` removed, no error any longer.

Comment: Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your route that it can receive params by simply ":id" not "user=:id". it will automatically resolve into "user=2"

```
  {
    path: 'something/create/:id',
    component: SomethingComponent
  }
```

Comment: I did it, and removed #new, now I've got this : NavigationError(id: 4, url: '/supervision/create?user=3', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'supervision/create')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hash within your route, you have to turn on the hash location strategy
`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})`

And for the query params change your router path like

`path: 'something/create/:id`

Comment: Please check my comment to Daddelbod's answer.

Comment: can you change your route from `/something/create/:id` to `/supervision/create/:id` @kazu

Comment: I just did, changed in route and component, but still the same error.